# No contacts in Empathy after upgrading to 3.3.2 (Ubuntu 11.10 x64)

Tags: gnome, empathy, dependencies

I recently upgraded to empathy 3.3.2 per the `ppa:telepathy/ppa` repository and suddenly all the contacts I had from Facebook chat, GTalk and MSN Messenger dissapeared even though the accounts window said that empathy is connected to them.

I've tried removing the accounts and adding them again, I've tried removing empathy 3.3.2 its dependencies and the telepathy repository and reverting to empathy 3.2.0.1 but the problem stayed even after downgrading.

Could it be I missed some important dependency that stayed with its latest version or maybe it's something else...

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: oohh man the only thing I can say is that I have the same problem (exactly the same) but Im running ubuntu 11.10 x32 . The only thing I can contribute to you was that when a contact try so talk with me ans sent me a message i could see the chat window and talk with him, howeverI cant see the contacts and select any of them.

Comment: This appears to be a problem still as of Ubuntu 12.04 and empathy 3.4.2.3 which seems to have a bug with the contact list. The protocol selection box for account is greyed out.

Comment: This appears to be a bug.  Have you considered looking at the [Empathy project page](https://launchpad.net/empathy) at Launchpad, and considering reporting a bug?

Comment: As others have said, this is a bug. [I recommend reporting it as one using the guidelines here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are hitting this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1018504. This should have been fixed upstream and works now in quantal and has been pushed to precise (12.04) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check `View > Offline` Contacts. They should appear there. (Do they not?)